# Compare Every line of file1 with every line of file2

Tags: linux

I have 2 files.

c1.log

```
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
```

c2.log

```
E1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
E2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
E3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
F1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
F2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
F3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
F4W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
```

I have to compare 2nd column of every line in c1.log with 2nd column of every line of c2.log. If it matches then it should print output in one line

```
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    E1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
```

Also, output should be logged in new file. let's say c3.log
Please help.

Thanks
Moses

Comment: So you are expecting seven rows of output from your sample inputs? D1W with each of E1W E2W E3W, and D2W with each of F1W F2W F3W F4W.

Comment: Yes Paul_Pedant

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple python script for you, which will do that:

```
address1 = input("Enter first file address:\n")
address2 = input("Enter second file address:\n")

data1 = []
data2 = []
with open(address1) as file:
    data1 = file.read().split('\n')

with open(address2) as file:
    data2 = file.read().split('\n')

if data1[-1] == "": data1.pop()
if data2[-1] == "": data2.pop()

for i in data1:
    for j in data2:
        if i.split(' ')[1].strip() == j.split(' ')[1].strip():
            print(i + ' ' + j)
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed

Answer (score 1):

Or, assuming your files are sorted on `-k2`

```
join -j2 -o 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 c1.log c2.log
```

Output:

```
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe E1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe E2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe E3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff F1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff F2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff F3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff F4W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
```

Answer (score 1):

`join` can do most of the work for you.  It joins matching lines from two files, matching on the second field like this:

```bash
$ join -j 2 c1.log c2.log
/u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe D1W E1W
/u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe D1W E2W
/u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe D1W E3W
/u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff D2W F1W
/u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff D2W F2W
/u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff D2W F3W
/u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff D2W F4W
```

Which gives you your match and the first column of c1 and c2 on one line.
Join needs the input files to be sorted. If they are not, you can sort them on the fly:
`join -j2 <(sort c1.log) <(sort c2.log)`. This is shell-magic. `<( some command )` will look like a file to `join` or any other command that wants a file.

Let's process those further:

```
$ join -j 2 c1.log c2.log | while read match c1 c2; do printf '%s %s\t%s %s\n' $c1 $match $c2 $match; done
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    E1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    E2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    E3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    F1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    F2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    F3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    F4W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
```

**Done!**

Here's the commands nicely wrapped, so you can paste them into a script if need be:

```bash
join -j 2 c1.log c2.log \
| while read match c1 c2; do 
  printf '%s %s\t%s %s\n' "$c1" "$match" "$c2" "$match"
done
```

If you do not need a tab between the two parts [@bu5hman has a better answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561404/364705).

**Update:**
You can get join to insert tabs, too:
`join -t'      ' -j2 -o 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 <(sort c1.log) <(sort c2.log)`
The space after `-t'` is a literal tab.  Press Ctrl+V, then TAB for that.  Plus I'm doing inline sorting of the files.

```bash
$ join -t'      ' -j2 -o 1.1 1.2 2.1 2.2 <(sort c1.log) <(sort c2.log)
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe        E1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe        E2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe        E3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe        F1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe        F2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe        F3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    
D1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe        F4W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff        E1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff        E2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff        E3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/fe    
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff        F1W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff        F2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff        F3W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff    
D2W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff        F4W /u02/app/oracle/db/ggs/current/dirdat/ff
```

Comment: Caveat on join command, from the man page: "Important:  FILE1  and  FILE2  must be sorted on the join fields." Also, the join uses the current LC_COLLATE rules. Personally, I always export LC_ALL="C" anywhere that sorts, diffs, or joins.

Comment: Good catch. Updated. Personally I `LANG=C` in all my shell-scripts :-)

Comment: Thank you, it's working.

Comment: How to redirect output to a new file of this 

join -j 2 c1.log c2.log \
| while read match c1 c2; do 
  printf '%s %s\t%s %s\n' "$c1" "$match" "$c2" "$match"
done

Comment: Easy enough: add `> your_outputfile` after `done`.  You may want to check out the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), specifically [Section 20](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).  Input/Output-Redirection is an important concept.  An alternative would be to add `| tee -a your_outputfile` (see `man tee`), so you can watch the output while it is written.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that c1.log, c2.log and the following script are present in same directory, this should work.

```
while read i
do
 c1_array=( $i )
 string1=${c1_array[1]}
 while read j
 do
   c2_array=( $j )
   string2=${c2_array[1]}
   if [ $string1 = $string2 ]
   then
    echo "$i    $j"
   fi
 done < c2.log
done < c1.log
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working.

Comment: How to redirect output to a new file of this 

while read i
do
 c1_array=( $i )
 string1=${c1_array[1]}
 while read j
 do
   c2_array=( $j )
   string2=${c2_array[1]}
   if [ $string1 = $string2 ]
   then
    echo "$i    $j"
   fi
 done < c2.log
done < c1.log

Comment: You can use redirection operator '>' . Replace echo "$i $j" statement by echo "$i $j"  > FILENAME.

Comment: Abhishek, It is giving only 1 line (last line) output in new file, instead of 7 lines

Comment: My bad. Replace '>' by '>>'. This should work

Comment: That has serious inefficiency for large files. It reads c1 once, but it reads the whole of c2 for every line in c1. That makes it O(n*n). It uses arrays to split input lines, where it could use IFS. It assigns to the string variables when it could compare fields or array elements directly. It appends every line separately when it could redirect the whole output at the end of the outer while.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek. It's working.